# cvQueryFrame doesn't return null

Tags: opencv

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( filename );
int nFrames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty( capture , CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT );
printf("Frame count - %d\n", nFrames);
while(1){
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if( !frame ) {
        break;
    }

}
```

nFrames == 101
but cycle doesn't stop after 101 iteration, why?

Answer (score 1):

`cvQueryFrame` returns an `IplImage` pointer. Based on the old documentation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html), it *may or may not* return NULL in the event of an **error**. In addition to checking for if it's NULL, you will probably want to check if the returned `IplImage*` has valid data to see if you actually got a frame or not.

Or better yet, switch to using the [C++ interface](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html):

```
VideoCapture cap( filename ); 
//check if we succeeded
if(!cap.isOpened())  
{
    //...
}

Mat frame;
for(;;)
{
    //get a new frame from camera
    bool got_frame = cap.read(frame); 

    if(!got_frame)
        break;

    //...
}
```